# Correct settings when it's for both print and screen?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Let's say I'm designing a logo or some other artwork that it's both for printing and screen. How should I set my ai file? CMYK or RGB? Align to grid or not? For instance, when I "save for the web" and my artwork is not align to grid and CMKY, will that affect the result?
Do you create separate files for print and screen?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi kyle, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

Generally there are *several files* needed when creating a logo. It is rare that "one file rules them all" so to speak. Unless the logo itself is so simplified that some variations can be ignored.

It's a good idea to create CMYK, Spot color, one color greyscale, *sometimes* one color non-greyscale, and RGB files for any brand.

In addition, there may also be a need to variations greater than the color space. A logo may be somewhat simplified for reduced size use. For example, look the UPS logo has some slight variations for color use:

[image] [image] [image]

If you need these for print and for web, they would need all the formats I listed above, totaling roughly 15 separate files for a single logo.

So **yes**, you create multiple files.